# Mysql Database optimization help in Laravel and eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have created this schema for order management for my larval food delivery system.
How can I optimize this? Currently, this will call 5 queries every time I load the order details with the relations.
Basically, I want to merge some tables will this be okay or is this design good we can consider 5 queries?

```
Orders
----------
id primary key
total FLOAT DEFAULT 0
delivery_time DATETIME Nullable
status VARCHAR(50)
===============

order_items
----------
id primary key
order_id FK
product_id  NULLABLE
name VARCHAR (100)
name_cn VARCHAR (100)
price  FLOAT
quantity
image
===============

order_addresses
----------
id primary key
order_id FK
address  VARCHAR (199)
address_details  VARCHAR (199)
name  VARCHAR (50)
phone  VARCHAR (20)
===============

order_payment
----------
id primary key
order_id FK
transaction_id
payment_method
pay_amount
status
===============

===============

order_shipping
----------
id primary key
order_id FK
method_id FK
name VARCHAR (50)
title VARCHAR (100)
fee  FLOAT
```

Comment: Simply ask yourself: Can an order have multiple items? Yes. Can it have multiple addresses? Maybe? Can it have multiple payments? Multiple shippings? A separate table makes sense if the answer is remotely positive. If it is definitely negative, and will always be negative, the table can me merged with the order table.

Comment: "larval food" -- Caterpillars?

Answer (score 0):

"call 5 queries every time" -- Unless you have an antiquated computer, don't worry.  My rule of thumb is "start worrying at 40 queries for one web page."  But there are still two things to consider.

- Are the tables properly indexed for speed.  Let's see the `SELECTs`.
- Might it be useful to do `JOIN` to avoid multiple round trips to the server.
- If your server is far away, the round-trip time may be worth worrying about.

I agree with the Comment that you should *usually* merge table together when the mapping between them is 1-1.  This is usually obvious when the `JOIN` is on the `PRIMARY KEY` of each.

Meanwhile, it is better to have monetary value in some size of `DECIMAL`, not `FLOAT`.  Similary "quantity" should probably be some size of `INT`.